# Why does i have to input 3 numbers instead of 2?

Tags: c

My code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b ;
    printf ( "Enter values of a and b: " ) ;
    scanf ( " %d  %d ", &a, &b ) ;
    printf ( "a = %d b = %d\n", a, b ) ;
}
```

When I execute in terminal, I have to input 3 numbes instead of 2 for the code to be executed:

```
Enter values of a and b: 12 10 5
a = 12 b = 10
```

I'm sorry for my lack of knowledge, I'm new to C language. Thanks for your time.

Comment: In `scanf` format strings, white space has a meaning. It means read a indefinite amount of white space. In your string, the trailing white space indicates that the scanning is not done after scanning the second number. Because the indefinite amount of white space is only terminated after reading something else (or the end of the input), you have to enter something else, which doesn't need to be a number.

Comment: Long story short: Fix your format string. Make use of the return value of `scanf`. Consider taking interactive input -- programs asks, user types and hits enter -- in two stages: `fgets` the line, then `sscanf` that line. Report errors.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I understood now, i'm really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does i have to input 3 numbers instead of 2?

```
      scanf ( " %d  %d ", &a, &b ) ;
                      ^
```

This space ignore `'\n',' ',...` i.e enter,space..., so this scanf continues until a non white space character is found in here (5)

```
Enter values of a and b: 12 10 5
```

the 5 is in the buffer you can check this by add this

```
scanf("%d",&a);
printf("%d",a);
```

after `printf ( "a = %d b = %d\n", a, b ) ;` will print `5` and it did not ask for input.

So change your code to

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b ;
    printf ( "Enter values of a and b: " ) ;
    scanf ( "%d %d", &a, &b ) ;
    printf ( "a = %d b = %d\n", a, b ) ;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter values of a and b: 12 10
a = 12 b = 10

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 2.406 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i understood now :))). I'm really appreciated.

Comment: @Trần Thiên     feel free accept the answer, if you got it.

Answer (score 0):

when you scan(Take) input from the user you should use scanf function and if you want to take more than one input you can use

```
scanf("%d%d%d",&input1,&input2,&input3);
```

without any spaces between %d or with single space(%d %d) as if you write space the compiler will think that there is additional input should be entered so the solution for your issue is (removing space between %d%d)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b ;
    printf ( "Enter values of a and b: " ) ;
    scanf ( "%d%d", &a, &b ) ;
    printf ( "a = %d b = %d\n", a, b ) ;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to remove the spaces either before the first `%d` or between the `%d` directives; the problem is the space at the _end_ of the format string. The `%d` directive automatically ignores whitespace characters, so spaces are not _needed_, either; but a space in a `scanf()` format string indicates to match _zero or more_ whitespace characters. The problem with the last space is that it matches the `\n` when the user presses ENTER, and `scanf()` keeps trying to match more whitespace characters until there is a matching failure.